# How to write part of a list to a csv?

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I have data in these lists. I need to use these certain elements at the beginning of the row, and then add 30 data points after. I understand how to splice a list, but I want to return those individual items from the list

```
w.writerow([sub_sub_header_list[0], data_list[0:29]])
w.writerow([sub_sub_header_list[1], data_list[30:59]])
w.writerow([sub_sub_header_list[2], data_list[60:89]])
w.writerow([sub_sub_header_list[3], data_list[90:119]])
```

I get something like this:

`Team Stats, [u'310', u'5291', u'1018', u'5.2', u'27', u'11', u'289', u'377', u'598', u'3879', u'26', u'16', u'6.3', u'190', u'398', u'1412', u'6', u'3.5', u'73', u'88', u'857', u'26', u'193', u'27.5', u'13.0', u'Own 27.6', u'2:21', u'5.40', u'27.4']`

When I want:

`Team Stats, [310, 5291, 1018`,...] and so forth.

Comment: Look up the `csv` package fro reading & writing CSV files.  You'll have a much easier time than if you try to format the information yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use base python functions to write csv file.

Lets say your data is as follows:

```
# elements converted to strings:
data_list = list(map(str, numpy.random.randint(1,100,20)))
sub_sub_header_list = ['A','B','C']
```

Following code will produce desired list:

```
rowsize = len(sub_sub_header_list)
outlist=[]
# create header:
outlist.append(",".join(sub_sub_header_list))         
# create rows:
for i in range(0,len(data_list)-rowsize,rowsize):
    outlist.append(",".join(data_list[i:i+rowsize]))  
# show format:
print("\n".join(outlist))
```

Output is in the needed format:

```
A,B,C
16,72,38
79,4,37
93,19,77
87,54,87
26,4,17
73,59,56
```

And csv file can be produced by:

```
with open("outfile.csv", "w") as f:     
    f.write("\n".join(outlist))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do keep in mind that CSV's are structured in a tabular fashion (like excel). You have the header first, then the data for each column of the header on separate rows. When you do a `writerow` you must provide it with the actual values, for specific columns, for the current row that's being written. You've basically written a couple of lists in your CSV on a each column by doing `w.writerow([sub_sub_header_list[0], data_list[0:29]])` which is essentially `w.writerow([1, 2...], [3, 4,...])`, that's why you got in the CSV data like:

```
u'[1,2,..]', u'[3,4,...]'
```

It was basically treating each list as an individual cell, and converting it to string so that it can store it in the CSV (that's where the `u''` comes from).

You basically have to keep a referenced index throughout the vector, since it's a 1-dimensional data structure that has the series appended one after another.

```
import csv

pf = open("out.csv", "w")

csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(pf, fieldnames=["A", "B", "C"])
csv_writer.writeheader()

LENGTH = 3  # number elements per column
data_list = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]

for i in range(LENGTH):
    csv_writer.writerow({
        'A': data_list[i],
        'B': data_list[i+LENGTH],
        'C': data_list[i+LENGTH*2],
    })

pf.close()
```

and the output would be something like:

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

If I deciphered your question correctly, something like this would do it:

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest


def grouper(n, iterable, sentinel=object()):
    """ Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks. """
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    for t in zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=sentinel):
        yield list(elem for elem in t if elem is not sentinel)


# Example usage.
data_list = [u'310', u'5291', u'1018', u'5.2', u'27', u'11', u'289', u'377', u'598',
             u'3879', u'26', u'16', u'6.3', u'190', u'398', u'1412', u'6', u'3.5', u'73',
             u'88', u'857', u'26', u'193', u'27.5', u'13.0', u'Own 27.6', u'2:21',
             u'5.40', u'27.4']
sub_sub_header_list = [u'sub_header_0', u'sub_header_1', u'sub_header_2',
                       u'sub_header_3']

output_filename = 'grouped_data.csv'
group_size = len(sub_sub_header_list)
with open(output_filename, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for i, group in enumerate(grouper(group_size, data_list)):
        row = [sub_sub_header_list[i%group_size]] + group
        csv_writer.writerow(row)

print('File {!r} written.'.format(output_filename))
```

Here's the contents of the csv file it created given the sample data:

```
sub_header_0,310,5291,1018,5.2
sub_header_1,27,11,289,377
sub_header_2,598,3879,26,16
sub_header_3,6.3,190,398,1412
sub_header_0,6,3.5,73,88
sub_header_1,857,26,193,27.5
sub_header_2,13.0,Own 27.6,2:21,5.40
sub_header_3,27.4
```

Note that since the number of items in the `data_list` wasn't an exact multiple of the number in the `sub_sub_header_list`, the last row isn't as long as the ones before it.